# Angular.js Bind ng-model with ng-repeat in input:checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an App using Angularjs v1.69 
I Get a Json Response of Time Slot
The below is the Current Code:

```
$scope.TimeSlotList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("TimeSlots"));
Console.log($scope.TimeSlotList);
```

Output:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "time": "7am - 10am"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "time": "10am - 1pm"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "time": "1pm - 4pm"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "time": "4pm - 7pm"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "time": "7pm - 10pm"
}
]
```

and this is done in the partial

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form_pad20">
                    <label>Prefered Time</label>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="form-field field-destination">
                            <div class="radio-checkbox display_inline" ng-repeat="x in TimeSlotList">
                                <input id="check-{{x.id+9}}" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="TimeSlotList[$index]">
                                <label for="check-{{x.id+9}}">{{x.time}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The Required output is Whichever Checkbox is selected i want that value
For Ex: if the user select time slot 2 and 3
i want to send 23 to the backend
i.e Timeslot-2 and Timeslot-3 should return true 
or something else i want output as

```
var FinalTime="23";
```

Trying to figure out from last 2 days 
But After Few Atempts basically th best solution was

```
ng-model="TimeSlot-{{x.id}}"
```

but this throughs error

```
Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'ScdItem.TSlot(x.id)' is non-assignable.
```

please can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `TimeSlotList` so that it contains a `selected` field. The initial value can be set to `false`.

```
$scope.TimeSlotList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("TimeSlots"));
$scope.TimeSlotList.forEach(item => item.selected = false);
```

Then bind the `selected` field to the corresponding checkboxes using `ng-model`:

```
<input id="check-{{x.id+9}}" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="x.selected">
```

This will change the `selected`'s value based on checkbox is checked/not checked. When you send the data to the server, you can extract the IDs of the slots based on the value of `selected` field, like this:

```
var selectedSlots = $scope.TimeSlotList
  .filter(slot => slot.selected) // Get all the selected slots
  .map(slot => slot.id) // Extract IDs of the slots
  .join(''); // Join the IDs to form a string
```

This way `selectedSlots` will contain the IDs of the slots selected.

Comment: Great That Work, can you explain me the last part of flitering and mapping you have done

Comment: @RushabhSheth -- Read [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: facing issue in npm install, it throughs error or remaining package , note i am angular.js v1.69

Comment: @RushabhSheth -- My solution works for AngularJS 1.6x. Failing `npm install` is not in the scope of this post. You might want to check `package.json` and create another question for the help related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form_pad20">
                <label>Prefered Time</label>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="form-field field-destination">
                        <div class="radio-checkbox display_inline" ng-repeat="x in TimeSlotList">
                            <input id="check-{{x.id+9}}" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="x.id" ng-change="checkTimeslot(x.id)">
                            <label for="check-{{x.id+9}}">{{x.time}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it only return true and random checkbox gets selected on clicking one

Comment: remove ng-model="x.id" from  checkbox then it will work fine.             like below                                                                                      
 <input id="check-{{x.id+9}}" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"ng-change="checkTimeslot(x.id)">